# ¿Cómo se modifica el texto del popup de una imagen de perfil?

Tags: soporte, perfil

Tengo entendido que se puede editar el apartado "Acerca de mi" en el perfil de usuario con algo parecido a meta tags que sirven para declarar un texto diferente al visible en el perfil para que este sea visible dentro del popup de imagen de perfil que ocurre al posicionar el cursor sobre imágenes de usuario al interno de los post.

Tengo la certeza de que esta funcionalidad existe, pero no he podido encontrar guías sobre como hacerlo, en mi caso tengo un perfil con mucha información y quisiera modificar el contenido del popup para que muestre solo la información esencial.

Comment: pues si se puede... aca tenes como... https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104810/141717... vale que lo traduzcas y dejes la respuesta aca!

Comment: gracias, lo haré

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta corta basada en este [artículo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104810/141717) es utilizar la siguiente línea

```
<!-- summary: Descripción deseada -->
```

al interno de tu descripción de perfil, de manera que tu perfil debería quedar algo así

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione illum,
voluptates iusto nisi earum ducimus itaque assumenda [lorem][1] sunt dicta!

<!-- summary: Descripción deseada -->

[1]: https://link "lorem"
```

Y al desplegarse el popup se visualizaría solo

```
Descripción deseada

lorem
```

> En el cual `lorem` es un link clicable